# PayPal Return URL : ColdFusion : Subscription ID

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, paypal-subscriptions, coldfusion-2016

How do I get the PayPal PaymentID (Subscription ID) returned?

It all works and I can send the crid (creditid : not paypal variable), and things return fine.
When PayPal returns the URL which works fine it attaches a "token"

cflocation send is fine and processes : contains this return url

`&return=http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/market/plans.cfm?uid=#log.uid#%26credits=#fee#%26src=add%26crid=#randout#%26act=#act#%26subscr=y"`

For those wondering the %26 has to replace the & inside the cflocation variable.

And PayPal Processes fine and returns fine and then adds the "&token=99U99932DH279724T" at the end of the URL. And sends this to the browser.

`http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/market/plans.cfm?uid=_sdfwre&credits=0.6&src=add&crid=cocaoie&act=u&subscr=y&token=99U99932DH279724T`

How do I get it to return the Subscription ID so I do not have to update manually.
The Token does not even show in any data in the transaction, not even Transaction ID: 2WV55753N50XX9999

No luck finding online or in PayPal documents yet.

UPDATE

Inside PayPal Preferences is "Payment data transfer"
That add some more variables.  So the Token is the UserTransactionID and a tx is PayPal Account TransactionID (mine).

But still no SubscriptionID.
But there is a "sig"
Which is like this:
99999lNhL+iFdy25cpmIKU/gJfwmKLgdFO45yRo6vO50syG7mKVRvnoMSrVBZhF1SjznPJwAhRAaKjS0bsoqZDSl+7RMsidrOd7aByFjdnc5jYysc/gq2m+E57kDSldm+0I0BWSYkocCefsJfXiv95zAQ1lauDF4K0Zw0999999=

So looking to see if I can decrypt that with my Datatransfer Identity Token.

Comment: Just to reiterate, if you are using Payment Data Transfer for anything important (such as updating information server-side) you shouldn't be doing this. Stop. Do something else. If you must continue to use a very old old classic integration without modern APIs and webhooks, there is IPN for server-side notifications.

Comment: Thx Preston, I will as it adds other data not required and nothing useful really that I can use.  For now - I can update user transaction ID with token.  I'll review some other options and newer API stuff.  I like the way I'm doing it... Its 1 line of code lol...

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the browser to supply any after-subscription information needed to proceed with business logic (such as recording the result to a database). The browser may or may not return after a subscription is completed: any number of things could interrupt the process on the client side. So, your knowledge and fulfillment of the subscription's status should be independent of the browser. Data in PDT for example, if any is returned, is serviceable for informational purposes only -- to show a the resulting status to the payer if it hasn't been obtained by other means. PDT is very old (20+ years) and its utility in current web integrations is close to zero.

---

For the current [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/),, you can [subscribe to the webhook event](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#link-subscriptions) `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` to be notified of the first as well as all future payments on a subscription. For reconciliation purposes, it's helpful to include a `custom_id` parameter when creating each subscription (in the `createSubscription` JS, generally, though you can also have it fetch and create with a server-side API if desired); this custom_id will then later be returned in that subscription's webhook events.

For older integrations, IPN was used instead before such webhooks existed. If such old integrations still need to be used for some reason, it's possible to use either the old IPN service or subscribe to [webhooks for classic NVP/SOAP APIs](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).